# Calcium chloride + starch desiccant packs inside PPE for ebola workers?

Tags: heat, enthalpy

(First question on stackexchange, apologies for any faux pas)

Ebola workers get drenched in sweat while working inside their personal protective equipment.  There's a discussion happening over on OpenIdeo about whether the desiccant packs used in shipping containers might help reduce humidity:
https://openideo.com/challenge/fighting-ebola/ideas/desiccant-embedded-ppe-suit-to-keep-ppe-dry-and-bearable

Questions for the chemists:

- What are the reaction products of a calcium chloride + starch desiccant pack with humid air?  In particular, would it generate any gases?  (That'd obviously be a problem inside an impermeable suit)
- The worker sweats to carry away heat evaporatively.  Presumably most of that body heat would need to pass through the desiccant pack as the sweat gets absorbed, and would need to be transmitted outside the suit in order to be worthwhile.  It looks like the reaction is also exothermic.  How much total heat would need to be removed from the pack, and is this going to be too much to dissipate?
- Any other risks to be aware of with this idea?

Comment: If the pack contains nothing but calcium chloride and starch, there would be no gaseous products at all.  The products would be hydrated calcium chloride and soggy starch (library paste if it gets wet enough.)  The assumption that the pack contains nothing but CaCl2 and starch may not be a good one though.  I'm not so much concerned with a gaseous product as with a dissolved product after the packet comes in contact with a large amount of sweat.